# Table weight ignored when text length is long?

Tags: android-linearlayout

I have the following xml layout - if editText_model text is fairly short then the table is split 50/50 by the weight value.

However the longer the text gets the more it squashes up the word Description. Why is it ignoring the 50/50 split?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="100">

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:text="Select"
                android:textSize="15sp"/>

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radioGroupAdd"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/RadioModel"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Test1"/>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/RadioPaint"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="Test2"/>

            </RadioGroup>
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="100">

        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tV_model"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:text="Description"
                android:textSize="15sp"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText_model"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:hint="Enter Description"
                android:inputType="text|textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
                android:minLines="3"
                android:text="testing long line of text 1234567890 123 456 77878 89 9 9d"
                android:textSize="15sp"/>


        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the layout_width, try putting 0dp.

Comment: Thanks - that did the trick. Been struggling for ages for this. Now to read up why 0dp?!

Comment: You let the width take up zero density-independent pixels but let the weight determine how much width should be :)